# Select Distinct and Get Count

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I need to get unique records from table and get their count of recurrence. I have query:

```
SELECT AwardReference.ownerID
FROM AwardReference
WHERE AwardReference.ownerType = 'song';
```

This returns something like:

```
ownerID
    1
    2
    4
    4
    5
    5
    5
```

I need do get something like:

```
ownerID  count
    1     1
    2     1
    4     2
    5     3
```

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Also I have to do this task with MS ACCESS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  AwardReference.ownerID ,
        COUNT(*) AS count
FROM    AwardReference
WHERE   AwardReference.ownerType = 'song'
GROUP BY AwardReference.ownerID
```

Comment: @user1237747 RE: "in MS Access it doesn't work at all" - Nonsense. I just pasted that query into Access 2010 and it worked fine. RE: "and generally it's not the thing I'm looking for" - Well, it's exactly what you *asked* for, so perhaps you need to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16284946/edit) your question to better explain what you really want.